# How to display webpage saved locally inside the webpage?

Tags: html, reactjs

I want to do an app in which at the server side I download html+css files from url, and then I send them back to client to display it.

I know that I can do something like this with iframes attribute but I don't want to display webpage from url, but from local html and css files.

Also, it is important to me that html file is not changed during the whole operation.

Comment: Have you considered a `docker` with nginx which serves file from your drive?

Comment: @Yaron Yes, I thought about it, although I'm currently working on localhost, I'm going to use docker later, I think. Do you have any idea how to do it without docker for now?
Please, correct me if I don't understand something.

Answer (score 0):

try it with nodeJS and express. On the Serverside fetch the Url, the User has given, and then simply send him the fetched HTML.

Comment: How do you suggest displaying the fetched html?